# Contiki Rebroadcasting a message

Tags: network-protocols, contiki

I would like to know how do I rebroadcast my message in Contiki, i.e. if `A` broadcasts the message to `C`, then `C` should again broadcast message to other nodes.

I used the posting of process using static event so that if I receive a broadcast message then I start a new broadcast process to rebroadcast the received message but it does not work.
Posting a process works with broadcast callback and unicast callback, but rebroadcasting does not work.

I can share the source code if necessary.

Comment: Are you using Rime stack or IPv6? If second, are you using UDP or TCP?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a primitive for this, called Trickle. It's better than just blind/naive re-broadcasts as they tend to lead to sth called the broadcast storm, where the wireless medium get congested by all the broadcasts being sent and re-sent. Instead, Trickle waits a random backoff before attempting to send a broadcast it received. If it, while backing off, hears it from another device, it drops it.

So, check for the trickle primitive.